# Move zeroes in array using ES6 features

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I’m new to ES6, trying to make a function that moves all zeros in the array in the last position of the array while preserving the original order of the array
E.g. `[1,0,0,0,2,3,4,5]` => `[1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0]`

```
 function moveZeros (arr) {
  let zeroArr = [];
    for(let i = 0;i < arr.length;i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 0) {
     zeroArr.push(arr[i]);
     arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  arr.push(...zeroArr);
  return arr;
}
```

This is my code its works fine, but I think this can be shorter more in using some ES6 features. Can someone provide a better solution

Comment: euuuh. What about a regular sort?...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That can be solved easily using `filter` function and `spread` operator, .

```
const moveZeros = arr => {
  const z = arr.filter(a => a === 0); // get all zeroes
  const nZ = arr.filter(a => a !== 0); // get all non zeroes
  return [...nZ, ...z]; // put the zeroes on the last position
};
```

Answer (score 5):

As requested in comments: what about `sort`?

```
arr.sort((a, b) => -!b)
```

It is for sure less performant, but hella shorter

**Old**

Onecompileman got an ok solution, but as OP wanted 'shorter' solution, i think we can reduce some unnecessary parts:

```
const moveZeros = a => [...a.filter(x => !!x), ...a.filter(x => !x)]
```

Answer (score 2):

@lucifer63 gave a short and good solution but the `double not operator` is both useless and confusing, removing it you'll get an improvement:

```js
const moveZeros = z => [...z.filter(a => a), ...z.filter(a => !a)]
moveZeros([1,0,0,0,2,3,4,5])
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Somehow i thought it would be actually more accurate to explicitly state that we want our value to be boolean right from the start, but yeah, you're right, it works without `double not`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduceRight` and if the element is 0 use `push` or if its not 0 use `unshift`.

```js
const arr = [1,0,0,0,2,3,4,5];
const res = arr.reduceRight((r, e) => (e === 0 ? r.push(e) : r.unshift(e), r), [])
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by splicing the result array either on the actual position or at an adjusted index, which counts the not null values.

```js
function moveZeroes(array) {
    return array.reduce((i => (r, v, j) => (r.splice(!v ? j : i++, 0, v), r))(0), []);
}

console.log(moveZeroes([1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```