# Why doesn't my MoveZeroes code modify the input array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to solve the following leetcode problem in JS: [MoveZeroes problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/move-zeroes)

The challenge is the following:
Given an array `nums`, write a function to move all `0`'s to the end of it while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements.

1.You must do this in-place without making a copy of the array.

2.Minimize the total number of operations.

Example:

```
Input: [0,1,0,3,12]
Output: [1,3,12,0,0]
```

In my code, I get the desired output on the console right before the end of the function, but it is being rejected and I would like to understand why.

This is my code:

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {void} Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
 */

var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
    let i = 0
    let length = nums.length
    while (i < length){
        if(nums[i] === 0) {
            nums = nums.slice(0, i).concat(nums.slice(i+1),0)
            length--
            continue;
        }
        length--
        i++
    }
    console.log(nums) //logs the desired result
};
```

I have seen similar questions to this:

1. [Using splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345529/move-zeroes-to-end-of-array-in-javascript-how-to-return-nothing)
2. [This one does not do it in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631233/move-zeroes-in-array-using-es6-features)
3. [Not doing it in-place either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179778/why-my-move-zeroes-function-is-wrong-answer-in-leetcode)

So, I understand that this might be a duplicate but I would appreciate direct feedback on my code. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, slice creats a new one, but time complexity won't be accepted anyway. Just use a simple pointer and swap.

Comment: See my solution here. It is similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948523/could-this-algorithm-be-made-better/60958056#60958056

Answer (score 1):

your code is violating the first rule:

> You must do this in-place without making a copy of the array

[slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) both returns a new array which means copying the original array;

you may use shift(), unshift(), sort() ... or swap the element values, that mutate the original array

Comment: Right, but by saving it to the same nums array, doesn't it get overwritten? This might be variables 101 but I thought I was using the same nums.

Comment: @DavidAguirreL it will overwrite the original array actually; arrays are only a reference in memery, each new array you create will have new reference

Answer (score 0):

`nums = nums.slice(0, i).concat(nums.slice(i+1),0)`

This line assigns the nums variable to a new array with the desired content. But the original array remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, your use of [`Array.slice(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`Array.concat(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) violate the constraints of the question. Quoting some particular sections from the Mozilla Developer Network pages on each of those functions:

- `Array.slice(...)`: "The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object..."
- `Array.concat(...)`: "The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but **instead returns a new array**. [emphasis added]"

I would *highly* recommend the usage of [`Array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, ... itemsToInsert]])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for this, which can be used not only to delete subsections of an array, but also to insert new elements into an array, all while modifying the array in-place. This versatility allows `Array.splice(...)` to function as an in-place replacement for both `Array.concat()` and `Array.slice()`.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I think my mistake was thinking that by assigning the calculation (concat and slice) to ```nums``` I was overwriting the original array but I was just overwriting the local copy of nums inside the function. So basically, my mistake had to do with how variables work. Or that is what I understand now.